# Unable to Copy UDF from SOLine (SO301000) to SOShipLine(SO302000) on Create Shipment Action

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created 2 UDF's in SOLine and SOShipLine, I am trying to copy values of those UDF's from SOLine to SOShipLine on "Create Shipment" action. my code is getting executed but the values are not getting copied. I am not sure whether  "SOShipment_RowPersisting" is a correct approach or not, or is there any other ways I can work this around. Though this RowPersisting have worked for me for copying fields from POOrder to APInvoice, Please suggest, Thanks

Following is my Code :

```
public class SOShipmentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
  {
        #region Event Handlers
        protected void SOShipment_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = (SOShipment)e.Row;
            SOShipLine row1 = new SOShipLine();
            if (Base.Document.Current != null)
            {
                foreach (SOShipLine tran in Base.Transactions.Select())
                {
                    SOLine xSOLine = PXSelect<SOLine, 
                        Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOLine.orderNbr>>,
                        And<SOLine.orderType, Equal<Current<SOLine.orderType>>>>>.Select(Base, tran.OrigOrderNbr, tran.OrigOrderNbr);
                    if (xSOLine != null)
                    {
                        SOLineExt soLineExt = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(xSOLine);
                        SOShipLineExt soShipLineExt = PXCache<SOShipLine>.GetExtension<SOShipLineExt>(row1);

                        soShipLineExt.UsrTerms = soLineExt.UsrTerms;
                        soShipLineExt.UsrWarrantyDate = soLineExt.UsrCustWarrDate;
                    }
                    return;
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When copying from one document to another I try and stay away from the document events since they will be executed even after the document has been created. As such I always try to hook in a method during the process of creating the document.

In your case you can override the "CreateShipmentFromSchedules" method in the SOShipmentEntry graph and move your code there. This will hook your code to execute only when converting from SO to a shipment.

```
public delegate Boolean CreateShipmentFromSchedulesDelegate(PXResult<SOShipmentPlan, SOLineSplit, 
        SOLine, InventoryItem, INLotSerClass, INSite, SOShipLine> res, SOShipLine newline, SOOrderType ordertype, 
        String operation, DocumentList<SOShipment> list);

[PXOverride]
public Boolean CreateShipmentFromSchedules(PXResult<SOShipmentPlan, SOLineSplit, SOLine,
        InventoryItem, INLotSerClass, INSite, SOShipLine> res, SOShipLine newline, SOOrderType ordertype,
        String operation, DocumentList<SOShipment> list, CreateShipmentFromSchedulesDelegate baseMethod)
{
    if (res != null && newline != null)
    {
            SOShipLineExt soShipLineExt = PXCache<SOShipLine>.GetExtension<SOShipLineExt>(newline);
            SOLine line = (SOLine)res;
            SOLineExt soLineExt = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt >(line);

            soShipLineExt.UsrTerms = soLineExt.UsrTerms;
            soShipLineExt.UsrWarrantyDate = soLineExt.UsrCustWarrDate;
    }

    return baseMethod(res, newline, ordertype, operation, list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jean, this is working fine, Thanks for the warning of not using document events.
May you please help me with the same for copying UDF from POLine (PO301000) to POReceiptLine (PO302000) using "Create Shipment" Action. I will be grateful to you.
Thanks